# PHP Date in Object's Properties

Tags: php, datetime

I've a object called 'Booking' with about 13 properties however while attempting to run the following code.

```
$bookingDateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$booking = new Booking(....,$bookingDateTime);
echo "START OF TEST <br>";
echo "$bookingDateTime <br>";
echo "$booking->bookingDateTime <br>";
echo "END OF TEST <br>";
```

It always echoes without the second DateTime.

```
START OF TEST 
2018-08-07 04:38:27 

END OF TEST
```

I am unsure what am i missing or is DateTime objects not allowed in PHP Objects?

Within Booking Object is the following

```
Class Booking{
    public $bookingDateTime;
    function __construct($bookingDateTime){
        $this->$bookingDateTime = $bookingDateTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to write it into variable

Comment: What are you doing with the `$bookingDateTime` constructor argument in the constructor?

Comment: @Phil $this->bookingDateTime = $bookingDateTime; just storing it in for later usage.

Comment: FYI, you do not have a `DateTime` instance (at least, not one we can see); you have a string.

Comment: I've got a feeling you're not seeing error messages. Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script

Comment: @Phil Did as you told however there isn't a different nor errors.

Comment: You'll need to show the relevant parts of your booking class if you want an exact answer, we can't guess what it looks like.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with the information you've provided ~ https://3v4l.org/lfVb6

Comment: @Qirel there isn't much worth mentioning though, will edit it

Comment: Ah, see there's your problem ~ `$this->$bookingDateTime = `. It should be `$this->bookingDateTime` which is what you have in your comment above. **Voting to close as typo**

Comment: @Phil you're totally right, i am totally disappointed at myself now.

Comment: This is why you should always provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make, we all have done so at one point. Though let this show why it is important that you share all the relevant parts of the code, there is no way we cold have known that without you posting your code :)

Comment: @Phil Thank you very much, and noted on that advice

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Phil and @Qirel in the comments for your help and advice, and everyone else.

It was a typo on $this->$bookingDateTime where the actualy problem was the extra $ in the object Booking.

```
$this->bookingDateTime = $bookingDateTime;
```

And read up on [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for future questions..

Comment: This really didn't need an answer

Answer (score 0):

you should write that

```
   Class Booking{
       public $bookingDateTime;
        function __construct($bookingDateTime){
          $this->bookingDateTime = $bookingDateTime;
       }
   }
```